# About Born-Oppenheimer approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, born-oppenheimer-approximation

I was just going through random lecture notes on Born-Oppenheimer approximation where I came across the following statement:

> We first invoke the Born-Oppenheimer approximation by recognizing that, in a dynamical sense, there is a **strong separation of time scales** between the electronic and nuclear motion, since the electrons are lighter than the nuclei by three orders of magnitude.

My confusion is: what does *separation of time scales* actually mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Separation of time scales* means that the characteristic times of movement (oscillation period, damping time, etc.) of the two systems are very different; this is also known as *adiabatic approximation*. If we take for simplicity that both nuclei and electrons perform oscillatory motion with periods $T_n$ and $T_e$, then $$T_e \ll T_n,$$ so that we can think of nuclei as static when solving the equations-of-motion for the electrons.